# Confused about voltage due to a point charge

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, voltage

If we have a point charge $q$ then at any point around $q$ we have an electric field due to our source charge $q$. We have a certain value of voltage or potential at this point, which is nothing but the work done by $q$ in moving a charge of $+1C$ from my reference point to infinity.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electric potential - different definitions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/302819/electric-potential-different-definitions)

Answer (score 0):

Electric potential (expressed as voltage) is a measure of the work required to move a unit of electric charge from some reference point to a specific point within an electric field, without producing an acceleration. (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential).

The electric field may be evaluated, for example, by the work done to move a charge FROM infinity to a point "r" in the field around "q", against the strength of the field.  In this case, the zero of potential is set at infinity, where no work is done.  This link explains why infinity is chosen as the zero for a point charge: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elepe.html#c3

This link (and its hyplerlink to Coulomb's constant) should illustrate and explain the concept fully: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/potpoi.html

It's important to remember that electric potential (voltage) is NOT potential energy.  It is, rather, the field strength that exists at a location in space (due to something generating the field), regardless of whether a charge occupies that location.  It may be evaluated by the work done to move a charge to that location against the strength of the field.  A charge at that location will then have potential energy, but the location itself does not have potential energy.

Comment: @my2cts if you say that is wrong, then what is correct you should mention that in your comment.

Comment: @yuvrajsingh The error has been corrected since my comment.